# Program Issue if statement not executing

Tags: java

### Heading

Program for Java class, supposed to be the game Pass the Pigs, tried everything, but cant get the special case marked by //FIXME to execute. Below is the code i have written. Any advice welcome on where i went wrong. I know there is a way to make it shorter using a for-loop, but i need to get this program working properly before trying to get it looking sleek. Thank you.

---

```
package ch07labx;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassThePigs {
    //names of pieces
    public static final String SIDER_NO_DOT = "Sider(no dot)";
    public static final String SIDER_DOT = "Sider(dot)";
    public static final String TROTTER = "Trotter";
    public static final String RAZORBACK = "Razorback";
    public static final String SNOUTER = "Snouter";
    public static final String LEANING_JOWLER = "Leaning Jowler";

    //score for piece landings
    public static final int SIDER_NO_DOT_SCORE = 0;
    public static final int SIDER_DOT_SCORE = 0;
    public static final int TROTTER_SCORE = 5;
    public static final int RAZORBACK_SCORE = 5;
    public static final int SNOUTER_SCORE = 10;
    public static final int LEANING_JOWLER_SCORE = 15;

    //odds of landing
    public static final int SIDER_NO_DOT_PROB = 33;
    public static final int SIDER_DOT_PROB = 66;
    public static final int TROTTER_PROB = 76;
    public static final int RAZORBACK_PROB = 96;
    public static final int SNOUTER_PROB = 99;
    public static final int LEANING_JOWLER_PROB = 100;

    private static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pigRollOne = null;
        String pigRollTwo = null;
        int wholeTurnScore = 0;
        String userInput = null;

        do {
            int rollScore = 0;

            Random randGen = new Random();
            int rollOne = randGen.nextInt(100) + 1;
            int rollTwo = randGen.nextInt(100) + 1;

            int rollOneScore = 0;
            int rollTwoScore = 0;

            //rollOne outcomes
            if (rollOne <= SIDER_NO_DOT_PROB) {
                pigRollOne = SIDER_NO_DOT;
                rollOneScore = SIDER_NO_DOT_SCORE;
            } else if (rollOne <= SIDER_DOT_PROB) {
                pigRollOne = SIDER_DOT;
                rollOneScore = SIDER_DOT_SCORE;
            } else if (rollOne <= TROTTER_PROB) {
                pigRollOne = TROTTER;
                rollOneScore = TROTTER_SCORE;
            } else if (rollOne <= RAZORBACK_PROB) {
                pigRollOne = RAZORBACK;
                rollOneScore = RAZORBACK_SCORE;
            } else if (rollOne <= SNOUTER_PROB) {
                pigRollOne = SNOUTER;
                rollOneScore = SNOUTER_SCORE;
            } else if (rollOne == LEANING_JOWLER_PROB) {
                pigRollOne = LEANING_JOWLER;
                rollOneScore = LEANING_JOWLER_SCORE;
            }

            //rollTwo outcomes
            if (rollTwo <= SIDER_NO_DOT_PROB) {
                pigRollTwo = SIDER_NO_DOT;
                rollTwoScore = SIDER_NO_DOT_SCORE;
            } else if (rollTwo <= SIDER_DOT_PROB) {
                pigRollTwo = SIDER_DOT;
                rollTwoScore = SIDER_DOT_SCORE;
            } else if (rollTwo <= TROTTER_PROB) {
                pigRollTwo = TROTTER;
                rollTwoScore = TROTTER_SCORE;
            } else if (rollTwo <= RAZORBACK_PROB) {
                pigRollTwo = RAZORBACK;
                rollTwoScore = RAZORBACK_SCORE;
            } else if (rollTwo <= SNOUTER_PROB) {
                pigRollTwo = SNOUTER;
                rollTwoScore = SNOUTER_SCORE;
            } else if (rollTwo == LEANING_JOWLER_PROB) {
                pigRollTwo = LEANING_JOWLER;
                rollTwoScore = LEANING_JOWLER_SCORE;
            }

            rollScore = rollOneScore + rollTwoScore;

            //special cases
            if ((pigRollOne.equals(SIDER_DOT) && pigRollTwo.equals(SIDER_NO_DOT)) ||
                    (pigRollOne.equals(SIDER_NO_DOT) && pigRollTwo.equals(SIDER_DOT))){
                rollScore = 0;
                wholeTurnScore = 0;
                System.out.print("Rolling... " + pigRollOne +
                        " & " + pigRollTwo);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("this roll: " + rollScore);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("this turn: " + wholeTurnScore);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Pig out!");
                break;
            }

            if ((pigRollOne.equals(SIDER_DOT) && pigRollTwo.equals(SIDER_DOT)) ||
                    (pigRollOne.equals(SIDER_NO_DOT) && pigRollTwo.equals(SIDER_NO_DOT))){
                rollScore = 1;                                                             //FIXME
            }
            if (pigRollOne.equals(pigRollTwo)) {
                rollScore = 2 * (rollOneScore + rollTwoScore);
            }

            wholeTurnScore += rollScore;

            //screen outputs
            System.out.print("Rolling... " + pigRollOne +
                    " & " + pigRollTwo);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("this roll: " + rollScore);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("this turn: " + wholeTurnScore);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Roll again (y/n)? ");
            userInput = scnr.next();

            if(userInput.charAt(0) == 'n'){
                break;
            }
            }while (userInput.charAt(0) == 'y');

        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you test that condition with your immediate prior `if` statement (exactly that condition) and break.

Comment: Thank you, moving the not executing if-statement to after the if-statement the doubles rollScore seems to fix that issue. Greatly appreciated.